# swift access files from cache directory

Tags: swift, macos, nsfilemanager

Can I read files from /Users/myusername/Library/Caches/xxx?
Currently I get a permission denied error by using `fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(…)`

Edit:

This is what I need: 
I export .scss files from Sketch into: `Users/myusername/Library/Caches/…`.
After that I have to read the files with my swift application.

Cheers

Kenny

Comment: if that is the _cache_ dir you are talking to: `let cachesDirectory: URL? = FileManager.default.urls(for: .cachesDirectory, in: .allDomainsMask).first`, then __yes__, you can write anything into it, freely, obviously the OS empties this dir time after time, so don't use it for permanent storing (like you'd use `Document/` folder).

Comment: Nope :( 
This is what I need:

I export .scss files from Sketch into: Users/myusername/Library/Caches/…
After that I have to read the files with my swift application.

Comment: so, you may need to read [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW1), and being aware of this: _"`/Library` (macOS only) — Apps that share resources between users store those resources in this version of the `Library` directory. Sandboxed apps are not permitted to use this directory."_